# Stream has already been operated upon or closed while loop the content of a file

Tags: java

```
    String fileName = "C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\Downloads\\InformeModificacionesUnificado28102021-09.txt";
//  File file = new File(fileName);
//  output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
   
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
        map.forEach((caracterMal, caracterBien) -> {
            stream.forEach(x -> {
                String cadenaWena = "";
                cadenaWena = x.replaceAll(caracterMal, caracterBien);
                System.out.println(cadenaWena); 
                //output.write(cadenaWena);
            });
        });

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

When i am running this code for loop a file content, it's throwing me this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has
> already been operated upon or closed

What's the problem of that?

Comment: A `Stream` can only be acted on once, then it's "used up" so to speak. The simplest solution to this specific case would be put the `map.forEach()` **inside** the `stream.forEach` (i.e. iterate over the map once for each element in the stream).

Comment: Not working in my case, showing 0 elements like that @GenerousBadger

Comment: I don't know i did read a question that said "If you need to close a stream, then best practice would be to use the try-with-resources statement" , but here it's failing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stream can only be iterated through once. You're iterating it for every element in the map.

Stop using lambdas (generally, a straight `.forEach` on a stream is bad java code; you're losing checked exception, control flow, and local variable transparency and you gain nothing) and the problem goes away:

```
static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  var path = Paths.get(fileName);
  var lines = Files.readAllLines(path);
  for (var e : map.entrySet()) {
    for (String line : lines) {
      String cadenaWena = line.replace(caracterMal, caracterBien);
      System.out.println(cadenaWena);
    }
  }
}
```

This fixes many things:

- It reads the file once instead of over and over again. Memory access is a heck of a lot faster than disk access.
- It doesn't have crazy error handling (print half of the error, toss the other half in the bin, and just keep going? That's not good code).
- It's shorter.
- It uses the proper `replace` (which replaces *ALL* occurrences). `replaceAll` is a misnamed method that interprets the first argument as a regexp, and it clearly isn't in your case.
- It doesn't use pointless lambdas and thus is more flexible.

Comment: The drawback is that the file could be huge, and `readAllLines` might run out of memory.

Comment: True. However, given that the user Sysouts it, that seems highly unlikely. But if so: It is (I think) more likely then that the user actually wants to do some op on each line, and that order doesn't matter, and therefore the code should iterate through the lines once, and per line, iterate the entire map. There simply aren't enough details in the question, yet assuming every property of the pasted code is equally important also seems like pushing it. Should such a question just be downvoted/closevoted off SO for being insufficiently detailed? Not sure.

Comment: @k314159 and this is also a painful reminder that `Files.lines` does exist, but a `Files.lines` variant that returns an autoclosable Iterable does not, which is stupid. Files in general feels pretty underwhelming for a second take. Perhaps JSR310's `java.time` package was prescient: Only 3rd attempts are actually any good.